# ERROR:savegame_thread.cc(106)] Save failed

Tags: mips, cobalt

[0411/152557:INFO:application.cc(729)] User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux mipsel) Cobalt/9.28152-debug (unlike Gecko) Starboard/4
[0411/152557:INFO:debug_web_server.cc(312)] Debug web server running at: http://192.168.58.204:9222
[0411/152558:WARNING:savegame_starboard.cc(90)] PlatformWrite: Invalid StorageRecord: Signed in?
[0411/152558:ERROR:savegame_thread.cc(106)] Save failed.

could you help me check this error ?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file used for local storage is not writable.

Comment: I can only see this error log on Debug Mode .
Does it  need  that local storage is writable  only on debug mode , not on qa mode ?

Comment: No, it just means the log is removed in QA, as are most logs.